How can I get the list of registered browsers from a script?
In System Settings, Desktop & Dock, I have this:

How can I get the list of apps appearing in that dropdown from a script? AppleScript or even Zsh would be great.
I use different browsers for different clients, and use Slack/Teams/etc for communication. When working for Client X, I want links I click on to open in Client X's browser instance. So I would run a script that sets Client X's browser instance to be my default web browser. When I switch to Client Y, I would run the script again.

I suggest you to look at these 2 URL's:
https://www.felixparadis.com/posts/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line-on-a-mac/
Or
Set default web browser via command line?
Then your Applescript maintains a list of pair client/browser, and it looks for current client to set the associated default browser.
